# How to send SMS via 3G Modem - ZTE MF190

Tags: sms, modem, at-command

I have a modem ZTE model MF190 and would like send SMS through AT commands on the serial port. My problem is: when I send AT commands, the modem responds with an error **+CMS ERROR: 305**

Researched a lot about the error, and he is due some invalid character in the message, but am not writing anything wrong in the message.

check:

[image: commands sent]

The funny thing is that if I send an empty message, I get the SMS (obviously empty)

Someone has been there and knows how to configure or send SMS by this model of modem?

Comment: This is a non-answer, but you may solve your problem using PDU mode.

Comment: Yes, I tried that but the error persisted. I believe there is something I'm missing.

Answer (score 1):

The error seems to signify that one or more parameter values assigned to the AT command are invalid for a text mode initiated SMS.

What is the command string being sent?

Comment: I'm sending exactly the commands that are in the picture above. In that order.

Answer (score 0):

Try hitting Ctrl+Z instead of Enter.

EDIT 2016-04-05: Note for anyone doing this using `socat` or similar under *nix: you will need to hit Ctrl+V prior to hitting Ctrl+Z or it will suspend socat to the background instead of sending the control character to the port.